# execute put item request - AWS DynamoDB ios SDK

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Looked all over SO and through Amazon's docs as well, but couldn't find any solid documentation on how to make a put request using iOS SDK, specifically using Swift.

I gather that I need to instantiate an AWSDynamoDBClient first (https://aws.amazon.com/articles/7439603059327617) but don't see that appear as a type when I'm working in xcode.

I've honestly only got two lines of code after all this struggle:

```
var myDynamoDBPutRequest:AWSDynamoDBPutRequest = AWSDynamoDBPutRequest()
    myDynamoDBPutRequest.item = ["fbid": "test"]
```

I can't figure out how to run it, and doubt that request is set up properly anyway. I've also looked at PutItemInputs, but not sure how that differs from putRequest.item. If anyone can just point me in the right direction I'll be happy to investigate on my own - I'm just running out of places to look for good documentation :/

EDIT:

I've made a bit of progress, but still can't figure out how to properly create a put item input . Here is the code I have now:

```
 var myPutItemInput:AWSDynamoDBPutItemInput = AWSDynamoDBPutItemInput()
    myPutItemInput.tableName = "mytable"

    var myDynamoDB = AWSDynamoDB.defaultDynamoDB()

    myDynamoDB.putItem(myPutItemInput).continueWithBlock { (task:BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        if(task.result != nil){
            let myPutOutput = task.result as AWSDynamoDBPutItemOutput

            println(task.result)

        }else{
            println("task.result was nil for put item request")
        }

        return nil
    }//end put item task
```

right now I at least figured out how to execute the request, but the result is nil each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of `- putItem`:

```
let dynamoDB = AWSDynamoDB.defaultDynamoDB()

let putItemInput = AWSDynamoDBPutItemInput()
putItemInput.tableName = "testTableName"
let hashValue = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
hashValue.S = "testPutItem"
let stringValue = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
stringValue.S = "stringValue";
putItemInput.item = [
    "hashKey" : hashValue,
    "stringKey" : stringValue
]

dynamoDB.putItem(putItemInput).continueWithBlock { (task:AWSTask?) -> AnyObject? in
    if(task.error != nil) {
        println(task.error)
    }

    if (task.result != nil) {
        let putItemOutput = task.result as AWSDynamoDBPutItemOutput
        println(putItemOutput)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Even though it's in Objective-C, looking at the [integration tests](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSiOSSDKTests/AWSDynamoDBTests.m#L237) may help understand how to use Amazon DynamoDB with the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS v2.

Comment: thanks so much, this is just what I needed. Now able to update item attributes from my app!

Comment: Oh one more thing - I noticed that when I run this if I provide a hashKey that is already an existing item in the table then it overwrites the entire item. What method should I use to modify specific attributes of an existing item? - I think I should be using updateItem?